# Factorization of polynomials and the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm just learning about Complex Analysis and somehow the factorization of polynomials and the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra confuse me.

For example let $f(z) = z^9$. Then $f(z) = 0$ has according to the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra $9$ solutions (counted with multiplicity).

But why is it wrong to say that in this case there is exactly one solution? Namely, $z=0$. I know that $z^9 = (z-z_1)\dots (z-z_9)$ but shouldn't all $z_i$'s equal 0?.

Comment: $0$ is the only root with multiplicity 9...

Comment: All $z_i$ are indeed equal to $0$.

Comment: There is a difference between counting roots with multiplicity and counting (the cardinality of the set of) roots (without multiplicity).

Comment: Illustrating the idea inherent in the comment of @LeeMosher, Mathematicians distinguish between $~[(z-0)],~$ $[(z-0) \times (z-0)],~$ and (for example) $~[(z-0) \times (z-0) \times \cdots \times (z-0)].$

Comment: This is precisely what "*counted with multiplicity*" means. Your $f(z)$ has $9$ roots counted with multiplicity, but only one distinct root.